# No module named 'azureml' >> !pip install azureml-core >> from azureml.core import Experiment

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.8, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am facing issues with **Azure ML** when i try to install the SDK with `pip install azureml-core` and then `import azureml.core` in my script. I do not understand how can it be possible to have this error assuming that the package installation is complete and confirmed by the terminal output with:

> "Requirement already satisfied: azureml-core in
> c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages"

*I have installed `azureml-core` package with the terminal and in the script with `!pip install azureml-core` but still get this error...*

**SCRIPT:**

```
!pip install azureml-core
from azureml.core import Experiment 
print(azureml.core.VERSION)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
      1 #CONNNECTING TO AZURE INSTANCE
      2 get_ipython().system('pip install azureml-core')
----> 3 from azureml.core import Experiment
      4 print(azureml.core.VERSION)
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml'
```

I am running the script locally with Python 3.8.10 on a Windows 10 last update and VSCode Insider.

> **My goal is to compute on an Azure instance without going through a remote because I would like to use my local fodlers.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER:**

I have no idea why but it is working now.
Try to restart your VSCODE and your compute instance.

BTW, to check the version use :

```
import azureml
print(azureml.core.VERSION)
```