# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml' in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am learning Azure ML from Microsoft tutorials, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-1st-experiment-bring-data). The first two tutorials ran fine, but this one is giving me the following error.

```
[stderr]Traceback (most recent call last):
[stderr]  File "train.py", line 8, in <module>
[stderr]    from azureml.core import Run
[stderr]ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml'
[stderr]
```

Working with Azure ML Studio and submitting the code to the environment, I am unable to find how to resolve this error.

I have checked that the package is installed (running on Azure ML studio so this is basic assumption, but I have tested as well). Following is the code 'run-pytorch.py' which calls the script 'train.py'

```
# run-pytorch.py
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core import Experiment
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = Workspace.from_config()
    experiment = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='day1-experiment-train')
    config = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='./src',
                             script='train.py',
                             compute_target='cpu-cluster')

    # set up pytorch environment
    env = Environment.from_conda_specification(
        name='pytorch-env',
        file_path='pytorch-env.yml'
    )
    config.run_config.environment = env

    run = experiment.submit(config)

    aml_url = run.get_portal_url()
    print(aml_url)
    print('Success...!!!')
```

Teh code snippet for train.py is as follows

```
# train.py
import os
import argparse
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from model import Net
from azureml.core import Run
...
...
```

Comment: You can refer to similar issues: [No module named 'azureml'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939332/no-module-named-azureml-pip-install-azureml-core-from-azureml-core-impo)

Comment: yeah. Tried that. Does not work either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following troubleshoot.
I have seen this when python called in your docker is not using env where Azureml package is installed hence…

- Can you ensure that you are calling using the correct python version  package inside from DOCKERFILE.
- Docker image that was cached and it didn’t have AzureML packages loaded. Renaming the image forced to reload the new docker image with AzureML packages.